# HTML5 LocalStorage not persistent on iOS after Power Off

Tags: ios, html, local-storage

I'm developing a web app for iPad (3G) that requires offline database storage.

At first I tried using HTML5's LocalStorage API.  When testing, I learned that if I navigate away from the page and power off the device (both iPad and iPhone), when I reopen the page later, my data cannot be accessed via LocalStorage (database appears to be missing).

I see this behavior at http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/examples/localstorage-halma.html with iOS devices, but Android devices (Droid X and Galaxy) and a PC running WinXP + Safari maintain my data across a restart.

I get appropriate behavior on the iOS devices using Webkit's own "client-side database storage", like what can be seen here: http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/.

Has anyone seen this problem with LocalStorage?
Does anyone know why the database wouldn't be maintained on iOS devices?
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: just a hunch...does the iPhone need a manifest file to know to keep the database?

Comment: @DA: Cache manifest files do not seem to be the solution. The database works just fine offline, but I think it's being deleted.  Tested a few online examples with manifests to no avail. (http://www.thedotproduct.org/experiments/offline_storage/ and http://diveintohtml5.org/examples/offline/halma.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the version of iOS.
I had this issues with v4.3 on an iPad, and v4.3.1 on an iPhone. 
v4.2.1 on an iPad works just fine.
v4.3.2 on an iPad will maintain the data across power-off, but NOT for clearing the cache.
I hope this helps someone else.